# onclick calling two functions simultaneously?

Tags: javascript

here is my code..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function clicker(){

    var thediv=document.getElementById('downloadoverlay');
    if(thediv.style.display == "none"){
        thediv.style.display = "";
        thediv.appendChild()
    return false;
    }
}
function clicker1(){
    var thediv1=document.getElementById('downloadbox');
    if(thediv1.style.display == "none"){
        thediv1.style.display = "";
        thediv1.appendChild()

    return false;
    }
}



</script>
```

on clicking the button.. the event should call two functions simultaneously.. help..??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add the handlers unobtrusively, from within your script. Something like:

```
function addHandler(etype, el,handlerFunction){
  if (el.attachEvent) {
   el.attachEvent('on' + etype, handlerFunction);
  } else {
   el.addEventListener(etype, handlerFunction, false);
  }
}
var myButton = document.getElementById('mybutton');
addHandler('click', myButton, clicker);
addHandler('click', myButton, clicker1);
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can, if you attach event listener: [IE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms536343%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), other [browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener).

Just keep in mind that they both won't end at the same moment, and one might get 'cut short', if site redirects, before second function is done.

Also, in this case, I would set CSS class on tag which contains both `#downloadoverlay` and `#downloadbox`. Instead of messing with `style` object directly.

Answer (score 1):

Just write one function that calls both. For example, you could write

```
function onClick() {
  clicker();
  clicker1();
}
```

And set `onclick="return onClick();"` on the element you care about.

Answer (score 1):

Just make another function to call both of them simultaneously

```
function callClickers(){
    clicker();
    clicker1();
}
```

Now add this to your button onclick

Comment: @Suren is there an error somewhere on the console? You should also add semicolons wherever you've missed them in your code. Its absence can muck things up

Answer (score 0):

You can call the two functions at once for the `onClick` event

```
    <button type="submit" id="mySubmit" onClick=" clicker(); clicker1()">Search</button>
```